How do I add a bottom border line in Apache POI 4.01?
I have been asked to help with moving a site that was written in Coldfusion 11 (using estimated Apache POI 3.10) that created an excel file to ColdFusion 2021 (using Apache POI 4.01). When I updated the server, the document creation part of the site broke. The filling part to shade a cell didn't work but I managed to get that fixed. What doesn't work now is adding a bottom border line.
Here is the original code that worked in v3.10 but doesn't work in v.4.01
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen.setDataFormat(createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat").getBuiltinFormat("($##,####0.00_);[Red]($##,####0.00)"))/>
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen.setBorderBottom(cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen.BORDER_DOUBLE)/>

If I try to run this, I get this error:

Element BORDER_DOUBLE is undefined in CELLSTYLECURRENCYBOTTOMBORDERDOUBLEGREEN.

I have looked at the docs for this function but I'm not understanding how to set this properly, I have tried setting it like this:
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen.setBorderBottom(cellStyleCurrencyBottomBorderDoubleGreen.THIN)/>

however this doesn't work as well.
I know I have to be close but can't seem to figure this out.
TIA
Update:
I was able to figure it out and hopefully this will help someone.
For Apache POI 4.01 ColdFusion 2021 this is how you set underlines for a cell.
The commented  code is the old way of doing this and the uncommented code above is the new way we need to call it with CF. 
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setDataFormat(createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat").getBuiltinFormat("($##,####0.00_);[Red]($##,####0.00)"))/>

<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderBottom(createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle").THICK)>
*<!--- <cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderBottom(cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.BORDER_DOUBLE)/> ** --->*

<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderTop(createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle").THIN)>
*<!--- <cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderTop(cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.BORDER_THIN)/> ** --->*


The border type is now in an own Enum instead of being a member of CellStyle. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setBorderBottom-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle- -> https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html.

Please post the solution you found as the answer, it might be helpful for other in the future.

I added it in the main page under update:

Answer posted by user in the question itself.
I was able to figure it out and hopefully this will help someone.
For Apache POI 4.01 ColdFusion 2021 this is how you set underlines for a cell.
The commented code is the old way of doing this and the uncommented code above is the new way we need to call it with CF.
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setDataFormat(createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat").getBuiltinFormat("($##,####0.00_);[Red]($##,####0.00)"))/>

<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderBottom(createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle").THICK)>
*<!--- <cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderBottom(cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.BORDER_DOUBLE)/> ** --->*

<cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderTop(createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle").THIN)>
*<!--- <cfset cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.setBorderTop(cellStyleCurrencyBottomTopBorderTan.BORDER_THIN)/> ** --->*

